# Draw a Minkowski diagram containing hyperbolic curves with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm wondering how could I make a Minkowski diagram with Tikz ?
I know there is already a post on that subject [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244472/how-to-make-a-minkowski-diagram) but the answer is not convenient for me.

I've already done this (i.e. the horizon lines)

[image: minkowski diagram]

But I would like the draw some hyperbolic curves on the right like you can see in the following picture :

[image: hyperbolic curves]

The equation for these is X^2 - T^2 = x^2. I would like to draw for some values of x.

Here's the code I made:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\tikzset{>=latex}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[black, thick] (0,-3) -- (0,3);
        \draw[black] (0,3) node [above] {$T$};
        \draw[black, thick] (-3,0) -- (3,0);
        \draw[black] (3,0) node [right] {$X$};
        \draw[green] (-2,-2) -- (2,2);
        \draw[green] (2,-2) -- (-2,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Mouvement hyperbolique et horizon de Rindler}
    \label{fig:minkowski-diagram}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.